# Using regexmatch & filter inside arrayformula (Google Sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a functional Google Sheets formula, that I try to modify, in order to execute as array formula, so that I no longer need to copy-paste in every cell. Can you help?

I try the usual approach:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:a)>0,iferror(transpose(filter(Dashboard!B:B, regexmatch(Dashboard!c:c, d2:d))),"-"),""))
```

but is not working (i think is repeating the result from the first line on the whole column).

the simple version:

```
=if(len(A2)>0,iferror(transpose(filter(Dashboard!B:B, regexmatch(Dashboard!c:c, d2))),"-"),"")
```

the array version:....?

Comment: Thank you for edit, player02. Here is the link to a sample version of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWGr35G7pFCZvqaLTpSpEaiv9t3ob9qwevX_GkunbDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume the problem is that I use a "FILTER" inside "ARRAYFORMULA". Is this impossible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D, TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(Dashboard!C2:C, ",")))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), " ", "|"))), TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Dashboard!C2:C, ","))<>"", "♠"&IFERROR(
 SPLIT(Dashboard!C2:C, ","))&"♦"&Dashboard!B2:B, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")), 2, 0), "-"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, player0. You are a wizard! Would it make a difference regarding the speed of formula if I had the same delimiter in "Emails" field on both sheets? (right now, I have "," in Dashboard" and "|" in the sheet with the array).

Comment: it wouldn't do much difference. regexextract requires to have  `|` delimiter/operator but that can be inserted even virtually so you can have any delimiter you wish